# How to make synchronous notification in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm using web forms in asp.net on my web app ,I need to make background process to check if there is new records inserted in my SQL Data Base every 10 minutes and give me a notification for it, How can i do that...Please help.

Comment: Take a look at SignalR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In global.asax Application_Start start a timer. When the timer fires use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem to call a function that does the DB-Query and notification via [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundTimerTenMinutes = new System.Timers.Timer(600000);
    backgroundTimerTenMinutes.Elapsed += backgroundTimerTenMinutes_Elapsed;
}

void backgroundTimerTenMinutes_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => DBQueryAndNotify(ct));
}
```